# While Segmenting an image, the loop skips a complete column

Tags: powershell, nested-loops, do-while, image-segmentation

I'm tasked with segmenting a screenshot and looping through the screenshot like a grid saving each predefined block as its' own image, much like the diagram below. The actual grid size is 10X8 It keeps skipping column 2. Please, educate me on my logical flaw as I've rewritten the if block 100 times, 10 different ways in the past 3 days to no avail.

```
        Col1 Col2 Col3
Row1     1     2    3
Row2     4     5    6 
Row3     7     8    9
```

```
"Starting to loop image for each ball"


    [int]$startCell = 1
    [int]$startRow = 1
    [int]$startColumn = 1
    [int]$totalLoops = 81


    [int]$startleftCoord = 293
    [int]$starttopCoord = 90
    [int]$startrightCoord = 385
    [int]$startbottomCoord = 160
    [int]$cellheight = 75
    [int]$cellwidth = 100
    [int]$offset = 2 


        Do 
        {         


            #get the current time and build the filename from it
            $Time = (Get-Date)

            [string] $FileName += "-cellshot"
            $FileName = "$($Time.Month)"

            $FileName += '-'
            $FileName += "$($Time.Day)" 
            $FileName += '-'
            $FileName += "$($Time.Year)"
            $FileName += '-'
            $FileName += "$($Time.Hour)"
            $FileName += '-'
            $FileName += "$($Time.Minute)"
            $FileName += '-'
            $FileName += "$($Time.Second)"
            $FileName += '-'
            $FileName += "$($Time.Millisecond)"
            $FileName += '-'
            $FileName += [string]$currentCell

            $FileName += '.png'

            #use join-path to add path to filename
            [string] $FilePath = (Join-Path $Path $FileName)



            if (!$currentCell -OR !$currentColumn -OR !$currentRow){
                "Initializing Globals"

                $currentCell = $startCell
                $currentColumn = $startColumn
                $currentRow = $startRow

            }  


            "Designate capture point"

           if ($currentColumn -gt 1 -AND $currentColumn -lt 11) {

                "Calculating side coordinates offset"
                $newleftCoord = $startleftCoord+($currentColumn*$cellwidth)
                $newrightCoord = $startrightCoord+($currentColumn*$cellwidth)

            } elseif ($currentColumn -eq 11) {

                "Resetting column coordinates "
                $currentColumn = $startColumn
                $newleftCoord = $startleftCoord
                $newrightCoord = $startrightCoord

                "Compensating for multiple rows offest"
                $newtopCoord = $starttopCoord+($currentRow*$cellheight)+$offset
                $newbottomCoord = $startbottomCoord+($currentRow*$cellheight)+$offset
                $currentRow++


            }else{
               "Getting number one"
                $newleftCoord = $startleftCoord
                $newtopCoord = $starttopCoord
                $newrightCoord = $startrightCoord
                $newbottomCoord = $startbottomCoord
            }



            "Current Column is " + $currentColumn
            "Current row is " + $currentRow
            "Current cell is " + $currentCell


            #save cellshot
            $cellBounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($newleftCoord,$newtopCoord, $newrightCoord, $newbottomCoord)
            $cellObject = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $cellBounds.Width, $cellBounds.Height
            $cellGraphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($cellObject)
            $cellGraphics.CopyFromScreen( $cellBounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $cellBounds.Size)
            $cellGraphics.Dispose()      
            $cellObject.Save($FilePath)





            $currentColumn++
            $currentCell++


        }Until ($currentCell -eq $totalLoops)
    Start-Sleep -Second 20
}




            #load required assembly
            Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms   

            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5       

            $ballarray = @{}

            Do {



                #run screenshot function
               # If ($ballarray.count -eq 20){
               #    GenScreenshot
               #     "Snapped screenshot - $Filename ."
               # }else{
                    Do{

                    GetNewBall
                    }Until($currentCell -eq 80)
                #}


                #$bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(307,129, 1060, 668)
                #screenshot $bounds $Filepath

                #Start-Sleep -Second 10
            }Until($ballarray.count -eq 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. $currentColumn is $null

2. "Initializing Globals"

3. $currentColumn = 1

4. $newleftCoord = $startleftCoord   #(is 293)

5. $currentColumn++                  #(now 2)

6. if ($currentColumn -gt 1)         #(Yes, it's 2)

7. $newleftCoord = $startleftCoord+($currentColumn*$cellwidth) 
                #= 293 + (2*100) 
                #= 493 

                #= jump from 293 to 493 = skipped column
```

Fix: count starting from 0 instead of 1.

```
293 + 0*100
293 + 1*100
293 + 2*100
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. For further elaborating as to "how & why" I was getting the results I was. Your "Fix" was exactly the solution. I envy you. @TessellatingHeckler Thank you for your generosity. I contribute and remain active to the community to get my rep above 15 and then credit your answer. Until then, hopefully someone strolls along and up votes.

Comment: @Eric Thanks :)  If you haven't already, look at PowerShell ISE - it comes with Windows - open your script in it, click on some code at the top of the loop, go to `Debug -> Toggle Breakpoint` (or F9 key), the line turns red - try different lines until one does. Then `Debug -> Run/Continue` (F5), it will run and stop at that line. You can `Debug -> Step Over` (F10 and F11) one line at a time. Really usefully you can hover the mouse over variables and see their values. Find exactly when the column position changes wrongly and why. Run code in the `[DBG]: PS >>` prompt, poke at the paused state.

Comment: (PS, if you want, you can tick the tick below the voting arrows and 'accept' my answer, which marks your question as 'answered' and gives me points).